# $G$ a group, with $p$ a prime number, and $|G|=2^p-1$, is it abelian?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

During my research I came across this question, I proposed it in the chat, but nobody could find a counterexample, so I allow myself to ask you :

$G$ a group, with $p$ a prime number, and $|G|=2^p-1$, is it abelian ?

Comment: It depends on the factorization of $2^p-1$, see https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_abelianness-forcing_numbers

Comment: Yes, but probably easier to solve. I doubt there is a prime $q$ for which $q^3 | 2^p - 1$, but the other 'case', two primes $q_1, q_2$ in the factorization for which $q_1 | q_2 - 1$ might very well be possible.

Comment: @Glorfindel, it's hard to believe that *never* happens, but a quick test in Mathematica shows that (I screwed up in Mathematica or) it doesn't happen for the first 50 primes.

Comment: @PéterKomjáth: No, we have then $2^p \equiv 2$ (mod $q^3$), respectively, $2^{p-1} \equiv 1$ (mod $q^3$).

Comment: One can use the Cunningham tables to do a quick check on the factors for more than 50 prime exponents. Gerhard "Not Computationally Motivated This Morning" Paseman, 2017.07.08.

Comment: I did a quick check for $p$ at most $800$ or so and found no examples. In the end this is a question about number theory and not group theory, and it might be difficult. For example it is an old open problem to determine whether $2^p - 1$ is squarefree for all primes $p$. If the answer to that old problem is yes, then you are asking whether every group of order $2^p - 1$ is cyclic.

Comment: http://msp.org/pjm/1967/22-3/pjm-v22-n3-p15-p.pdf

Comment: Indeed, your suggestion https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273976/g-a-group-with-p-a-prime-number-and-g-2p-1-is-it-abelian#comment679288_273976 is the same as [@spin's](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273976/g-a-group-with-p-a-prime-number-and-g-2p-1-is-it-abelian#comment679278_273976).

Comment: I have rolled back the edits to this old question, which seem to be purely cosmetic and done for promotion. Yes the question is appropriate for MO, but that doesn't mean you need to add some kind of "RL" label

Comment: If you are claiming that you can answer this question, then you can either add an answer below, or write up your work as a preprint in the normal academic way, or write it in a blog post and leave a link. Saying "I can answer this, can you?" is not a constructive use of this site, nor is it collegial.

Comment: @YemonChoi  Well, I would wait 500 years for the math community to find a complex 600-page solution, like for Fermat.